# Claim Based Authentication - Object Model and Impact on existing Web Service

Tags: web-services, authentication, claims-based-auth, claims

I have a farm in which is installed Sharepoint 2010 Foundation. On my principal app I have installed a web application that accepts windows authentication.
On that application I installed my Web Service and this works great.

Now I must pass to an Claim Based application, on the same farm I create it on another port (50000). The installation is successfull so that the application asks me "differently" the credential to accept.

Now, I have a "hopefully simple" question:
To the WS the access by Windows Authentication or Claim Based one is "free of charge"?

In other word, when a method is invoked, it already knows the SPUser who is invoking? Or may I change something in the code?

To access to the user who is invoking I can use the standard Object Model? Or I must use something else?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything remains as it is, you have a nice token of your claim that you can manage in your webpart, only that you will be forced to implement a custom provider claims to search for users or groups sull'ldap (people picker) and transform the result into a claim. I hope I explained myself

visit this link:
http://ldapcp.codeplex.com/